# Need help creating a highchart histogram in a Jupyter-Notebook

Tags: highcharts, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to embed a Highchart Histogram in a Jupyter-notebook. I've simplified the code down to 2 cells and a small dummy series for the actual data to try and limit any surrounding code that could be causing the issue. I am still continually getting an error 17 on the console(that the series type doesn't exist).  I'm thinking the problem is with importing the histogram-bellcurve module, but haven't been able to work around this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Cell 1:

```
%%javascript
require.config({
  paths: {
    highcharts: "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts",
    highcharts_hist: "http://code.highcharts.com/modules/histogram-bellcurve"
  },
  shim: {
    highcharts: {
      exports: "Highcharts",
      deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    highcharts_hist: {
      exports: "Highcharts",
      deps: ["highcharts"]
    }
  }
});
```

Cell 2:

```
%%javascript
$("#container").remove();

element.append('<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>');

require(['highcharts_hist'], function(Highcharts) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        'title': {
            'text': 'Highcharts Histogram'
        },
        'xAxis': [{
            'title': { 'text': 'Data' },
            'alignTicks': false
        }, {
            'title': { 'text': 'Histogram' },
            'alignTicks': false,
            'opposite': true
        }],

        'yAxis': [{
            'title': { 'text': 'Data' }
        }, {
            'title': { 'text': 'Histogram' },
            'opposite': true
        }],
        'series':  [{
            'name': 'Histogram',
            'type': 'histogram',
            'xAxis': 1,
            'yAxis': 1,
            'baseSeries': 's1',
            'zIndex': -1
        }, {
            'name': 'Data',
            'type': 'scatter',
            'data': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,11],
            'id': 's1',
            'marker': {
                'radius': 1.5
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi w_agi, your problem is definitely caused by wrong importing the histogram-bellcurve module. The same behavior you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w62pmcjh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google it would appear that this approach once worked, however your result now seems the default. From the [Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/#toc5), it appears that you need to load the module specifically.

In your case I had success with this approach (changes in cell 2):

```
%%javascript
$("#container").remove();

element.append('<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>');

require(['highcharts', 'highcharts_hist'], function(Highcharts, histogram) {
    histogram(Highcharts); // This is where the magic happens

    $('#container').highcharts({
        // ... for brevity
    });
});
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Ondkloss/46e7e070341df9a227cf2a00574efcaf) or [this nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/Ondkloss/46e7e070341df9a227cf2a00574efcaf/raw/7be6628f27c443c6a7e31a7dbe29388c8a5072fe/highcharts_with_histogram_module.ipynb) to see it in action.